# Drawing on overriden EditText does not work

Tags: android, canvas, android-edittext

I have problems with adding custom drawing commands to EditText subclass. I have overriden onDraw method, but the only command which works for me is `canvas.drawColor()`

I have this code (it's just for testing and debugging purposes:) which results in a blank canvas (white)

```
public class ClearableEditText extends EditText {

private Paint mPaint;
private Path mPath;

public ClearableEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init(){
    initPaint();
}

private void initPaint() {
    mPaint = new Paint(getPaint());
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    DebugLog.d(canvas.getWidth()+"px "+canvas.getHeight()+"px");
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), mPaint);
    canvas.drawText("text", 0, 30, mPaint);
}
}
```

Does anybody know why the `drawRect()` and `drawText()` commands aren't doing anything? I'm expecting something very funny:)

Comment: The question might be confusing, I know that by "clearing" the canvas makes the text disappear..I only have problem with not being able to draw over the text (the white color is there only for debugging purposes - to make sure I'm note overlooking something)

Comment: your Canvas is translated, try to verify it by calling Canvas.getMatrix and logging the Matrix

Comment: This is the matrix `Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, -1047589.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}`

Comment: so translate it by +/-1047589.0 and see what happens

Comment: yeah I see its translated by milion pixels on x axis..:) Do you know where the heck could this come from?

Comment: probably center alignment , what does getScrollX returns?

Comment: well, it returns exactly that value of the translation..the EditText is actually aligned to right.
and there's definitely not enough of content to make it scroll that far

Comment: so the problem is solved

Comment: Yeah actually the part of it contained in this question certainly is..I'm now able to see what I've drawn on the canvas. But there is now another issue: while scrolling the canvas seems to be only getting translated. (probably that's why there is that huge initial offset when aligned to right).
I want to have a small button aligned to the right of the content. But this way while scrolling it either gets out of the visible clip of the view, or it gets overdrawn again and again (when the edittext has also focus at the time of scrolling - it seems to be reusing previously drawn frames)

Comment: so it seems to be XY problem... http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: very funny..
why you rather don't convert yours comments to answer?

it works now completely, I've just forgotten to reset all shapes for each frame:)